# Images displaying issue on live server though working on local

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, ce-1.9.2.0, permissions

Product images are not displaying on live site though they are displaying on my local system. How can I solve this?

Magento: 1.9.2

Comment: so it works on production but not on local? Or vice versa? Check file permissions (775 for directory and 664 for files) and the owner. Also flush the cache and clear the image cache

Comment: Did you try these suggestions?

Comment: it worked with 777 premission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the permission of media folder to 777. It will work.